# Is it possible to apply 2D convolution to 1D data?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, convolution

Suppose that I have a 1D dataset with 6 features.

Can I apply a 2D convolutional neural net to this dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the engine you use, but in general, yes, of course.

For example, in the [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) height and width are separate variables, so nothing in your way to set one of them to 1 to have 1D data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly *reshape* the data to make it fit a 2D network. You could set the width or height to 1 as suggested by DamirTenishev, but you could also set the *features*/*channels* to 1 and treat the features as a height, if you wanted to convolve that way (would be a bit strange).